# Location updates not always start immediately

Tags: android, android-location

I have an application which starts a foreground service and requests location updates. The `LocationRequest` is configured using the following code:

```
locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 60 * 1000);
locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(30 * 60 * 100);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

i.e. I get updates every 10 minutes and want them batched by half an hour. (In reality, I get them more frequently when for example navigation is used, this is OK, I don't want to throttle it).

Sometimes, very often actually, when I start the application I don't get any location updates for a couple of minutes, even though `FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()` would return something (I have a lot of logging so I am 100% sure). What I can do, though, is to go to the Maps application, it very often has an immediate fix, and then my application gets the location update as well.

To me it seems like my application doesn't 'trigger' location tracking the way Maps does it. What do I need to do to make it better and have location updates start almost immediately?